# Handlebars handler for dropdown onchange event not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, onchange, express-handlebars

I'm using Express with Handlebars for front-end. When the selected option in the dropdown in `home.handlebars` changes, I want to trigger an event and read the value of the selected option in `index.js`. As I understand, I should use a Handlebars helper for this. I created a helper `server.js` (the Node.js backend) and added it to the `onchange` event for the dropdown. However, the handler does not seem to work. Here is my code:

`server.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const port = 3000;
app.use(express.static('public'));
var handlebarsHelpers = handlebars.create({
    helpers: {
        dropdownChange:  function (value) {
            console.log("helper running.");
            console.log("value is " + value);
            return value;
        }
    }
});
app.engine('handlebars', handlebarsHelpers.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', './views');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home', {layout: false});
});

<...>

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

`index.js`:

```
import * as d3 from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/d3@7";
import axios from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/axios';

const dataSet = async function getData() {
    return await axios.get('/data');
}

var courseData = [];



function getNodes() {
    //************************getNodes is the function that should eventually read the dropdown value************************
}

async function drawGraph() {
    const data = await dataSet();
    console.log(data);

    courseData = data.data;
    console.log(courseData);

}
drawGraph();
```

`home.handlebars`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Graph Chart</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 align="center">Graph Chart</h2>
    <div>
        <select name="select" id="select" onchange={{dropdownChange value}}>
            <option value="">Select a course...</option>
            <option value="course1">course1</option>
            <option value="course2">course2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <svg class="prereq-graph"></svg>
</body>
</html>

<script type="module" src="./static/js/index.js"></script>
```

How do I fix the issue of the Handlebars helper not working? Alternatively, are there other ways to pass the dropdown selected value from Handlebars to Express when the `onchange` event is triggered?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I remembered that Javascript's `addListener` is a thing and solved my issue